# Fetch lazy Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, lazyloading, spring-data-jpa

Я имею класс Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    @Pattern(regexp = "(.+)@(.+).(.+)", message = "Email address must contain @ and .")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Knowledge> knowledge = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();

    @Transient
    @NotBlank(message = "Name must be required")
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Set<Knowledge> getKnowledge() {
        return knowledge;
    }

    public void setKnowledge(Set<Knowledge> knowledge) {
        this.knowledge = knowledge;
    }

    public Set<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(Set<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addKnowledge(Knowledge knowledge) {
        this.knowledge.add(knowledge);
        knowledge.setUser(this);
    }

    public void removeKnowledge(Knowledge knowledge) {
        this.knowledge.remove(knowledge);
        knowledge.setUser(null);
    }

    public void addTask(Task task) {
        tasks.add(task);
        task.setUser(this);
    }

    public void removeTask(Task task) {
        tasks.remove(task);
        task.setUser(null);
    }

}
```

Так же имею репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface KnowledgeRepository extends CrudRepository<Knowledge, Integer> {
}
```

Предположим в нужном месте я достал entity по id, далее во время работы в некоторых местах мне нужны entity task(которые связаны с User), как я могу их достать в некоторых местах программы?

Comment: Приведите более конкретный припер. А так дергаете юзаре и достаете из него коллекцию с тасками

Comment: Я полагаю метод `getTasks`  вас по какой-то причине не устраивает?

Comment: Пример таков, что мне нужно всегда доставать допустим tasks только по необходимости в runtime коде

Comment: Почему, он меня устраивает, но пользоваться я им хочу при ленивой инициализации

Answer (score 0):

Если ваше поле помечено `FetchType.LAZY`, значит содержимое его вы можете получить только внутри одной транзакции для этого пометьте метод сервиса аннотацией `@Transactional` или сам класс, тогда каждый метод будет будет как отдельная транзакция. без этого при обращение к этому полю вы получите LazyInitializationException.
или можно обратиться отдельно к репозиторию тасков и найти их по id юзера

Comment: Вообще еще можно достать через @Query с помощью join fetch, просто это все отдельные запросы. Вы сказали при транзакции...у меня получалось только при первой транзакции, и то через getTask(), а после в другом месте, где есть транзакция, было исключение. То есть правильно я понял, что только по id доставать во время работы?

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov , если вам необходимо работать с этими полями, то вам не подходит 'FetchType.LAZY', вам лучше тогда использовать 'FetchType.EAGER' тогда они сразу проинициализируются

Comment: Мне с ними в одном случае нужно работать, а в других нет

Comment: тогда посмотрите про @NamedEntityGraph

Comment: Я смотрел и ее, он мне не совсем подходит

Answer (score 0):

А если определить в репозитории отдельный метод для получения юзера с тасками и когда нужны таски выдергивать юзера этим методом, к примеру как-то так:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "tasks")
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id=?1")
User getWithTasks(int id);
```

P.S. Для валидации email есть аннотация @Email javax.validation.constraints.Email